# Show tracks and via's in 3D view in the latest Altium Designer 20?

Tags: altium, 3d

I want to view the tracks and via's in Altium Designer 20 when I am in 3D view (**shift+s** is not what I want since that will hide the components and **only** show the tracks and via's).

How can I be in 3D view, leave everything intact, and on top of that show the tracks and vias like the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the opacity of the solder mask layers.  You can do the same with the core layers if you want to see inside.

Comment: In Preferences - Layer Colors I can't find opacity settings? In Board Insight Modes there is Heads Up opacity... Where can I find that where you've stated?

Comment: I'm using 19, but if I'm looking at the board in 3D and hit lower case L, the view configuration window appears.  The view options tab has the transparency settings